# Android : Set 666 permissions on /dev/video0

Tags: android, permissions

I have built an Android app which uses an external USB camera. The camera image is shown full-screen app takes screenshots, and stores them on the local file system. When the USB camera is connected, it creates and streams to the following folder;

/dev/video0

the folder is destroyed each time the camera is disconnected.

This issue is that my app doesn't have permission to read from this folder. So I have to set the permissions each time the camera is connected.

I have tried to get the app to set the permissions automatically, using the following code;

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"});
sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"chmod", "666", "/dev/video0"});        
sh.waitFor();
```

...which asks the user to grant Super User permissions, and  gives me feedback telling me that the user is now root - but I can see via terminal that the permissions haven't been changed on the folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Like almost every question of this type, your mistake is in thinking that "su" switches your program to running as root.  It does not, nor is it possible for any tool to do so.  Rather, what it does is run the given command program (in this case sh) as root. You are going to have to get that program to accept a chmod command and arguments, perhaps by piping it into the shell process once it is started. It's been covered countless times on here.

Comment: hi @ChrisStratton, can you give an example, or point me to one in this forum, as my searches haven't turned up anything useful, thanks

Comment: Look for su doesn't work type android questions, there are dozens if not hundreds

Comment: thanks @ChrisStratton, I had been looking for questions specifically about the folder I was interested in. You're correct, the right search found the answer. I needed to make my call using an OutputStream. Do you want to duplicate your comments as an answer, and I can accept it?

Comment: @ChristyHerron: I have two devices HTC One-X and Samsung Galaxy 7 inch tablet. While connecting WebCam to HTC One-X video0 folder is created under /dev folder. But the same folder is not creating inside Samsung Galaxy 7 inch. How to get video0 folder if it is not created? And inside Samsung Galaxy 10 inch device video0, video1, video2, video3, video11, video12, video12, video16, video02 files are already present without connecting camera. Do you have any idea about /dev/video* folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the following code which works great;

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("chmod 666 /dev/video0").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor();
```

For some reason, the command has to be sent via an OutputStream.

Answer (score 3):

the shell supports reading commands via stdin (like you are doing with the OutputStream) or as arguments to it's -c command line option. For example, this should work also if you'd rather not create the extra object:

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "/system/bin/sh -c \"chmod 666 /dev/video0\""});
```

this translates to executing in the shell:

```
su -c "/system/bin/sh -c \"chmod 666 /dev/video0\""
```

which you can try out first in adb if you want.

In this particular case, because you are only executing one command anyway, you don't really need the shell at all and can probably just call this:

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "chmod 666 /dev/video0"});
```

Also to add to the comment that you can edit the ueventd.rc file: that should work, but those files are either in the read-only /system partition (which is easily edited by remounting it with read-write) or more likely some ramdisk (gzipped cpio archive) that is flashed to a partition on the device. The latter won't be quite as easy unless you can find that ramdisk image on the flash chip, extract it, edit the file, recreate the cpio, and write it back to the flash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about the risks of giving those permissions to the camera, you can add

```
/dev/video*               0666   system     camera
```

to `/ueventd.rc`.

Comment: thanks @dtmilano, I have managed to use adb shell to add this line to /ueventd.rc using the vi editor. But I now have another issue - the line is removed after reboot, so I have no way of testing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Many ODMs use safe storage to rewrite **rootfs**, including `/ueventd.rc` on reboot. But this method is nice for custom ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to add the camera permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>